# Stop Microsoft edge to open pdf file every time

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, apps, system-apps, pdf

I am using microsoft Lumia 640 xl and windows 10. I am facing a problem from Microsoft edge. Every time i open a pdf file edge ( system app)  automatically opens and in case of heavy books it crashes many times even when i have onereader already installed on my mobile. So how to stop edge to open pdf every time. I tried to find the solution in forum also but failed. So how to get rid of edge.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Edge is set to open PDF files by default. You cannot change that Windows 10 Mobile. If you want to use your dedicated PDF viewer app then you must open PDF file through that app.

Comment: I tried One-reader app. Whenever I tried to explore that particular pdf file in app, file is not shown,it looks like edge has hijacked all pdf files. All other apps are failed. We are forced to open via edge. I can somehow tolerate edge but again it crashes many time while reading books through edge means not working for heavy pdf files. Any more suggestions......

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, including Windows 10 Mobile, Microsoft Edge is the default `.pdf` and ebook reader. 
In Windows 10 desktop you can simply change the default viewer under settings, but in mobile, the option is not available.

Download a `.pdf` reader app, and open the files through the app. I recommend [Adobe Reader](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/mobile-app/windows-phone.html).

Comment: answer to those guys who recommending pdf reader. If you choose a pdf on WhatsApp it automatically open error page and there is no way to choose a reader for opening pdf

Answer (score 0):

Only for **expert users** there is the possibility of changing a registry key. It changes also the file icon in explorer. I can write details if it is of interest for someone. I have done the change on my Lumia 640XL.
You can use Interop Tools to edit the registry. This is the main place to find it and learn about it:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-interop-tools-versatile-registry-t3445271

Please, always remember that change registry keys could not be safe.
The registry keys of file associations are here:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DefaultApplications

The default content of .pdf key is:
Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

For example if you use Acrobat Reader the string is:
AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobeAcrobatReader_ynb6jyjzte8ga

Comment: Please do. How do you edit the registry on Windows mobile 10?

Comment: Please expand, otherwise this is not an answer.